# How to set Background image for Layout in Android from file path

Tags: android

I want to set Background image for Layout in Android using random image.

I have 20 image in forder res/drawable, name images is: wallpaper1, wallpaper2, ... , wallpaper20.

my code:

```
RelativeLayout manHinhApp=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.manHinh);
ArrayList<Integer> arrImage=new ArrayList<>();
        arrImage.add(R.drawable.wallpaper1);
        arrImage.add(R.drawable.wallpaper2);
        arrImage.add(R.drawable.wallpaper3);
        arrImage.add(R.drawable.wallpaper4);
        arrImage.add(R.drawable.wallpaper5);
        arrImage.add(R.drawable.wallpaper6);
        //........
        arrImage.add(R.drawable.wallpaper20);
        Random random=new Random();
        int position=random.nextInt(arrImage.size())+1;
        manHinhApp.setBackgroundResource(arrImage.get(position));
```

It works correctly.

I want to make it more short. my code:

```
 RelativeLayout manHinhApp=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.manHinh);
Random random=new Random();
        int position=random.nextInt(20)+1;
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("org.anddev.android.ViewsViDu:drawable/wallpaper"+position, null, null);
                                                                   //ViewsViDu is my name project
        manHinhApp.setBackgroundResource(resID);
```

but it is don't work.
thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working for me:

```
String nameimg="wallpaper"+position;
int resID= MainActivity.this.getResources()
                    .getIdentifier(nameimg, "drawable",
                            MainActivity.this.getPackageName());
 manHinhApp.setBackgroundResource(resID);
```